# nginx - unicorn - django 502 bad gateway. Connection to project.sock failed

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I just deployed my django app on Digital Ocean and I keep getting this 502 error.

I've double checked all my conf files and my nginx error logs shows:

```
connect() to unix:/root/path/project_name.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to ups$
```

I think that it might be a permission problem, how can I change the permission of the project_name.sock file if it's not yet there/created?

Any ideas?

Comment: it's probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205263/nginx-getting-permission-denied-when-connecting-to-unicorn

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've read all the similar questions but everything looks in order..

Comment: Try to move the location of your socket to the /tmp folder

Answer (score 0):

port 80 for listening to incoming traffic via browsers
that is why type:

```
ufw allow 80
```

then reload nginx & gunicorn.. should work well after that.